# How to handle body element events in a controller in ExtJS6?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have a basic grid panel where I render custom `<span>` element inside one of the columns. I am trying to catch the click events on this element and handle them in a controller.

The problem is that inside the listener `this` refers to `Window`, so I can't even fire an event.

```
Ext.define('MyList', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'mylist',
    controller: 'mylist',

    listeners: {
        body: {
            click: function(e, el){
                //this.fireEvent('onTagClick');
            },
            delegate: 'span.tag',
            scope: this
        },
    },

    columns: [
        {
            text: 'Name', 
            dataIndex: 'name', 
            renderer: function(value, metaData, record){
                return '<span class="tag">tag</span>' + value;
            }
        },
    ]
});
```

I can fire a global event with `Ext.GlobalEvents.fireEvent()` but running into some strange issues or bugs with duplicate event invocations after the grid gets reloaded. I want to see if there is a way to avoid global events.

Answer (score 0):

Found one solution by attaching the listener directly from the controller, `this` would refer to the controller then:

```
Ext.define('MyListController', {
    alias: 'controller.mylist',

    init: function(){
        this.getView().on({
            body: {
                click: function(e, el){
                    this.onTagClick(el);
                },
                delegate: 'span.tag',
                scope: this
            },
        });
    },

    onTagClick: function(el) {
        console.log("clicked", el);
    },
});
```